# Find common employees between departments

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL. I have a table called works(EID,DID,PCT_TIME) and PCT_TIME is not used here.

The question I have is: Find the two departments ( represented by DID) who have the highest number of employees ( he's represented by EID) in common.

I've tried that:

```
select count(*) as max_NBR_COMMUN from (select EID from WORKS group by EID having count(EID) >= 2) as temp
```

to get the number of employees common to two departments but it doesn't work.
EDIT: I've seen your answer and I thank you all, I'm a business student so not familiar with computer science and therefore sql.
So my final request is

```
select count(distinct wa.eid) as num_eids_in_common, wa.did, wb.did 
from works wa 
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid and wa.did < wb.did 
group by wa.did, wb.did 
order by num_eids_in_common desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Which database are you using? (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: *but it doesn't work* ... not very helpful. Please describe undesired result or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this.

```
create table works ( eid int not null, did int not null );
insert into works values (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (4,4);
select * from works order by eid;
eid         did       
----------  ----------
1           1         
1           1         
1           2         
1           3         
2           1         
2           2         
3           1         
4           4
```

Note that employee 1 has multiple entries in department 1, a curve ball.

To find out which employees are in more than one department we need to join `works` with itself, a [self-join](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_self.asp). This is like any other join, but table aliases are mandatory.

```
select wa.eid, wa.did, wb.did
from works wa
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid
 and wa.did != wb.did;
```

This joins with any row that has the same employee ID but different department ID, because we don't want to see employees in our own departments.

```
eid         did         did       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2         
1           1           3         
1           1           2         
1           1           3         
1           2           1         
1           2           1         
1           2           3         
1           3           1         
1           3           1         
1           3           2         
2           1           2      
2           2           1
```

Employee 1 shows up multiples times because it has multiple entries in `works`, remember the curve ball? We can remove these duplicates by [selecting only the distinct rows](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp).

```
select distinct wa.eid, wa.did, wb.did
from works wa
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid
 and wa.did != wb.did;

eid         did         did       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2         
1           1           3         
1           2           1         
1           2           3         
1           3           1         
1           3           2         
2           1           2         
2           2           1
```

We can also avoid counting each department pair twice by joining with `wa.did < wb.did` instead of `wa.did != wb.did`.

```
select distinct wa.eid, wa.did, wb.did
from works wa
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid
 and wa.did < wb.did;

eid         did         did       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2         
1           1           3         
1           2           3         
2           1           2
```

Now we have a list of all the employees who are in more than one department, and their departments.

We get the number of employees in common by [grouping by](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_groupby.asp) both department IDs and counting the employees.

```
select count(distinct wa.eid) as num_eids_in_common,
  wa.did, wb.did
from works wa
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid
 and wa.did < wb.did
group by wa.did, wb.did;

num_eids_in_common  did         did       
------------------  ----------  ----------
1                   1           3         
1                   2           3         
2                   1           2
```

Finally we get the one with the most in common by sorting num_eids_in_common in descending order and limiting it to 1 row.

```
select count(distinct wa.eid) as num_eids_in_common,
  wa.did, wb.did
from works wa
join works wb on wa.eid = wb.eid
 and wa.did < wb.did
group by wa.did, wb.did
order by num_eids_in_common desc
limit 1;

num_eids_in_common  did         did       
------------------  ----------  ----------
2                   1           2
```

Comment: I think GROUP BY should come before ORDER BY in your last query

Comment: yes the final request that works is in my post , but I have to thank him because he made me understand the thing